# Is there a C header for Linux that includes a function for checking if a certain key is pressed

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I'm trying to make a snake game for the terminal, I can't find any input function in any header i've tried that doesn't wait for input but gives me what is currently pressed.

Edit: I'm not using ncurses for terminal ui and I don't want to have to use it

Comment: Try [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: I would have already used ncurses to make this game but it flashes too often as it clears the screen when drawing the windows

Comment: There's also the [Linux input subsystem APIs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/input/input.html).

Comment: will using it require root access from the program?

Comment: Linux is a multi user system, so accessing the hardware directly will require some sort of special permissions (usually a group membership or some other trickery with permissions, possibly via udev). For examples, look at a game library like `libsdl2` and check out what people do to make it run without X (it uses the same `/dev/input` subsystem mentioned above).

Comment: If used properly, ncurses will not flash the screen when redrawing.

Comment: If you restrict your input possibilities to the terminal, no special permissions are needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in the Standard Library.

You'll have to use another library (POSIX with `<termios.h>`; [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses); ...) and/or implement the functionality with system/terminal calls.

Comment: There is a "standard" library for this.  System calls are not necessary.

Comment: Added `<termios.h>` to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the terminal and not any graphics system, you want either the `ncurses` library which handles both input and efficient screen drawing, or you want the `termios` library, which handles raw input from a terminal.

Using termios, you would want to put the terminal input in raw mode, and either input single characters, or set a delay to wait for a character or return nothing if it timed out.

Answer (score -1):

I'm wondering how you currently get your input, if not waiting for it (trough some interface). And if that's the case (which btw. is), is it really so hard to implement a struct or even a simple primitive to store the last pressed key? I bet, the code required for that is shorter than your question.

Have a look at evdev (even if you don't want to use evdev, it gives you insight on how to access/use the input device directly):

- [evdev (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev)
- [libevdev (documentation)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/)
- [libevdev (software)](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev/)

Comment: The evdev library is for direct device use, not for use with terminals.

Comment: @user10489 The question is not tagged that way, so just the OP uses the word terminal (once), doesn't mean that the OP is looking for terminal only solutions.

Comment: Evdev is a good resource.  But I suspect it isn't what this user is looking for.

Comment: @user10489 The OP is looking for 'anything' that provides the last (pressed) key event. My purpose was not to suggest any such library, my point was to show, that in one way or another, you have to wait for events and that it is not a big deal to store the last event (if not provided by the interface). edev was just an example, on how the lowest level of the input event mechanism in linux looks like. From there it is not hard to imagine, how all the other interfaces are implemented.

Comment: The OP mentioned terminal.  If terminal use is involved, it could very likely be on the other end of a remote ssh session, in which case evdev and all of the rest of the hardware access libraries are useless and irrelevant.  Terminal is in the queston, not having a tag for it is probably something that should be fixed.